# Problem with Wifi with Raspberry Pi Jessie

Tags: wifi, ssh, connection

I'm trying to connect to the WIFI with my Raspberry Pi 2, Jessie 4.4.21+.

Right now when I do it with an ethernet cable connecting to the laptop(http://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/connecting-raspberry-pi-without-monitor-beginners/), I am able to use SSH via putty through raspberrypi.local for the Hostname. And I am able to use the WIFI as well. I used ifconfig to find out the ip address, but when I tried to unplug the ethernet cable and try to connect through Putty the ip address I just obtained, it doesn't work.

ifconfig:

```
wlan0
Link encap: Ethernet   HWaddr 00:c1:41:16:04:5b
inet addr: 172.25.101.42 Bcast: 172.25.111.255 Mask: 255.255.240.0
inet6 addr: fe80:2c1:41ff:fe16:45b/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAT MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:592 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:170 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:101741(99.3KiB) TX bytes:23394(22.8KiB)
```

Heres is my config:

```
/etc/network/interfaces

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet manual

auto wlan0
auto-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

And the wpa_supplicant.conf:

```
network={
ssid = "abc"
pairwise = CCMP
group = CCMP
key_mgmt = WPA-EAP
eap = PEAP
identity= "blahblah"
password = "kfpwkfpwk"
phase2 = "auth= MSCHAPV2"
}
```

Am I doing or understanding it wrong?

Comment: include `ifconfig`

Comment: @Milliways included!

Comment: I doubt very much that is the output of `ifconfig`

Comment: @Milliways hmm ive only included the wlan0 part, there is the eth0 and lo as well.

Comment: The output of ifconfig that you gave - is that after or before you unplugged the ethernet? If it's after, then it really should work - did you try pinging that IP, and did you try SSH'ing in via the IP rather than the host name?

Comment: @Jodes it is before I unplugged the ethernet. After I unplugged it, I tried to use that IP address to SSH in. I'll update the ipconfig again when I have the monitor( don't have 1 right now) to display the ipconfig without the ethernet connected.